# Customizing CAS server with a custom MFA provider and a custom flow

Tags: java, spring, cas

I am trying to customize a CAS server by adding a custom multi-factor authentication (MFA) provider. Specifically, I want to modify the flow of the Authy provider. After login, I want users to arrive at a page where they can enter a phone number. This phone number will then be used to send a verification code.

Here is my webflow configurer:

```
public class AuthyMultifactorWebflowConfigurer extends AbstractCasMultifactorWebflowConfigurer {

    /**
     * Webflow event id.
     */
    public static final String MFA_AUTHY_EVENT_ID = "mfa-authy";

    public AuthyMultifactorWebflowConfigurer(final FlowBuilderServices flowBuilderServices,
                                             final FlowDefinitionRegistry loginFlowDefinitionRegistry,
                                             final FlowDefinitionRegistry flowDefinitionRegistry,
                                             final ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext,
                                             final CasConfigurationProperties casProperties,
                                             final List<CasMultifactorWebflowCustomizer> mfaFlowCustomizers) {
        super(flowBuilderServices, loginFlowDefinitionRegistry, applicationContext,
                casProperties, Optional.of(flowDefinitionRegistry), mfaFlowCustomizers);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doInitialize() {
        multifactorAuthenticationFlowDefinitionRegistries.forEach(registry -> {

            val flow = getFlow(registry, MFA_AUTHY_EVENT_ID);
            createFlowVariable(flow, "phoneNumber", String.class);

            flow.getStartActionList().add(createEvaluateAction(CasWebflowConstants.ACTION_ID_INITIAL_FLOW_SETUP));

            createEndState(flow, CasWebflowConstants.STATE_ID_SUCCESS);

            val initLoginFormState = createActionState(flow, CasWebflowConstants.STATE_ID_INIT_LOGIN_FORM,
                    createEvaluateAction(CasWebflowConstants.ACTION_ID_INIT_LOGIN_ACTION));

            createTransitionForState(initLoginFormState, CasWebflowConstants.TRANSITION_ID_SUCCESS, "phoneNumberEntryState");

            val phoneNumberProperties = CollectionUtils.wrapList("phoneNumber");
            val phoneNumberBinder = createStateBinderConfiguration(phoneNumberProperties);

            val phoneNumberEntryState = createViewState(flow, "phoneNumberEntryState", "phoneNumberEntry", phoneNumberBinder);
            createStateModelBinding(phoneNumberEntryState, "phoneNumber", String.class);
            val setPrincipalAction = createSetAction("viewScope.principal", "conversationScope.authentication.principal");
            phoneNumberEntryState.getEntryActionList().addAll(setPrincipalAction);
            createTransitionForState(phoneNumberEntryState, CasWebflowConstants.TRANSITION_ID_SUBMIT,"phoneNumberEntryAction");
            
            val phoneNumberEntryActionState = createActionState(flow, "phoneNumberEntryAction",
                    createEvaluateAction("phoneNumberEntryAction"));

            createTransitionForState(phoneNumberEntryActionState, CasWebflowConstants.TRANSITION_ID_SUCCESS, CasWebflowConstants.STATE_ID_SUCCESS);
            createTransitionForState(phoneNumberEntryActionState, CasWebflowConstants.TRANSITION_ID_ERROR, "phoneNumberEntryState");

            setStartState(flow, initLoginFormState);

            registerMultifactorProviderAuthenticationWebflow(getLoginFlow(), MFA_AUTHY_EVENT_ID,
                    casProperties.getAuthn().getMfa().getAuthy().getId());
        });
    }
}
```

And here is the Thymeleaf view for the page where users enter their phone number

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout" xmlns:th="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      layout:decorate="~{layout}">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"/>

    <title th:text="#{cas.mfa.authy.pagetitle}">Authy Login View</title>
    <link href="./cas.css" rel="stylesheet" th:remove="tag"/>
</head>

<body>
<main role="main" class="container mt-3 mb-3">
    <div layout:fragment="content" class="mdc-card card p-4 m-auto w-lg-66">
        <form method="post" id="fm1" th:action="@{/login}" th:object="${phoneNumber}">
            <input type="hidden" name="_eventId_submit" value="LOGIN" />
            <input type="hidden" name="execution" th:value="${flowExecutionKey}" />
            <input type="hidden" name="geolocation" />
            <div id="msg" class="banner banner-danger alert alert-danger my-2" role="alert"
                 th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('*')}">
                <span th:each="err : ${#fields.errors('*')}" th:utext="${err + ' '}">this error block and text is only shown
                    if there are errors</span>
            </div>

            <div class="cas-field form-group my-3 mdc-input-group d-flex">
                <div class="mdc-input-group-field mdc-input-group-field-append">
                    <div class="d-flex caps-check">
                        <label for="phoneNumber"
                               class="mdc-text-field mdc-text-field--outlined control-label mdc-text-field--with-trailing-icon">
                            <span class="mdc-notched-outline">
                                <span class="mdc-notched-outline__leading"></span>
                                <span class="mdc-notched-outline__notch">
                                    <span class="mdc-floating-label">Number</span>
                                </span>
                                <span class="mdc-notched-outline__trailing"></span>
                            </span>
                            <input class="mdc-text-field__input form-control pwd"
                                   type="text"
                                   name="phoneNumber"
                                   id="phoneNumber"
                                   th:field="*{phoneNumber}"
                                   size="25"
                                   autocomplete="off" required />
                        </label>

                    </div>
                </div>

                <button class="mdc-button mdc-button--raised" accesskey="l">
                    <span class="mdc-button__label">Validate</span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</main>
</body>
</html>
```

When I launch the server, I can log in, but after that, I receive a page without the field to enter the phone number. The console logs the following error:

```
2023-07-20 16:51:33,812 ERROR [org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine] - <[THYMELEAF][https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-1] Exception processing template "phoneNumberEntry": Error during execution of processor 'org.thymeleaf.spring5.processor.SpringInputGeneralFieldTagProcessor' (template: "phoneNumberEntry" - line 42, col 36)>
2023-07-20 16:51:33,817 ERROR [org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter] - <Cannot forward to error page for request [/login] as the response has already been committed. As a result, the response may have the wrong status code. If your application is running on WebSphere Application Server you may be able to resolve this problem by setting com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.invokeFlushAfterService to false>
```

I'm not familiar with Spring Web Flow, so I'm unsure how to proceed. Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0):

### The Problem

The main problem seems to be that you try to access field `phoneNumber` inside object `phoneNumber` of type `String` (see [Thymeleaf documentation](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#expressions-on-selections-asterisk-syntax) if unsure about the asterisk syntax):

Java:

```java
            createFlowVariable(flow, "phoneNumber", String.class);
```

Thymeleaf:

```
        <form method="post" id="fm1" th:action="@{/login}" th:object="${phoneNumber}">
            ...
                            <input class="mdc-text-field__input form-control pwd"
                                   ...
                                   th:field="*{phoneNumber}"
```

Note that the last line above is referenced from the logs you provided (while `th:field` being a Spring extension to Thymeleaf):

```
2023-07-20 16:51:33,812 ERROR [org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine] - <[THYMELEAF][https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-1] Exception processing template "phoneNumberEntry": Error during execution of processor 'org.thymeleaf.spring5.processor.SpringInputGeneralFieldTagProcessor' (template: "phoneNumberEntry" - line 42, col 36)>
```

### The Fix

I think the simplest fix should be to change the web flow object from `String` to a proper "form bean class" with 1 field (and potentially other fields when more input is needed in the future). I.e., when we focus just on the key parts of the code again, it could look like this:

Java:

```java
            createFlowVariable(flow, "phoneNumberForm", PhoneNumberForm.class);
```

Thymeleaf:

```
        <form method="post" id="fm1" th:action="@{/login}" th:object="${phoneNumberForm}">
            ...
                            <input class="mdc-text-field__input form-control pwd"
                                   ...
                                   th:field="*{phoneNumber}"
```